Implementing search feature for all activities in HomeActivity
I am new to android development and I started my first project.
My question is that I am building an app with different activities and fragments that contains a lot of items, I want to implement a search feature in the HomeActivity that can search for items in all other activities and fragments and displayed them in a fragment.
All the items strings I am using in the app are inside a single xml file.
Is that possible to establish? I don't want to implement a search option for every activity and fragment.
I tried to look for the answer here but I didn't find any.

maybe start by implementing a search that works for one scenario, then see how you can expand on that

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry if my request is not that clear,
I will explain more about the issue, I am developing an app that has some activities (HomeActivity, ConvertActivity, etc...), in one of this activities I made a fragment to display items in a recyclerview, the list displayed depend on the item clicked in the previous activity, that mean I have a lot of list to display. My question is, if I want to  implement a search option that cover the whole app how should I do it ? I don't want to search inside a specific list in the recycler view but to search for all the items I have in the app. I hope it's clear.
